# Interesting Puzzle About Indian And Brazilian Marbles

Tags: weighing

There are 8 boxes each containing 8 marbles. There are two kinds of marbles – Brazilian kind and Indian kind. Each marble of the Brazilian kind weighs 12 units and
each marble of the Indian kind weighs 11 units. Of the 8 boxes there is one box in which all of the marbles are of the Indian kind, all others contain marbles of the Brazilian kind only. You are given a weighing scale (assume it’s digital). How will you find out which box has the marbles of the Indian kind with only one weighing?

I have just started studying discrete math and I am still getting the hang of combinatorics. Any contribution is very much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45998/weigh-eight-balls-and-find-the-lighter-one

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie I wouldn’t say so. This has a very different solution based on the fact only one weighing is allowed

Answer (score 7):

I’ve seen something similar before. You are missing one very key part of information in this question, and that’s

> that you can take marbles out of these boxes. (This isn’t ruled out in the question, just not mentioned)

Without this I don’t think this is solvable. Assuming this was meant to be included, the solution is as follows:

> Label all boxes $1$ - $8$. Now take $1$ marble from box $1$, $2$ from box $2$, $3$ from box $3$ etc until you have $36$ marbles.
>
> Now put all the marbles on the weighing scale. The weight shown will be $36 \times 12 - X = 432 - X$
>
> If you solve for $X$, then $X$ is the number box with the Indian marbles in them.

Why this works:

> If all marbles were Brazilian the weight would be $36 \times 12 = 432$. But as not all marbles are Brazilian, not all weigh $12$. As Indian marbles weigh one less than Brazilian marbles, the amount the total weight is less than $432$ will be how many Indian marbles there are. As the number of marbles represents the number box, we know what box has the Indian marbles.

Comment: You could reduce the number of marbles that need to be weighed by: rot13(gnxvat mreb zneoyrf sebz gur svefg obk, bar zneoyr sebz gur frpbaq, naq fb ba, svanyyl gnxvat frira zneoyrf sebz gur rvtugu obk. Nf orsber, lbh jbhyq trg n qvssrerag jrvtug sbe rnpu cbffvovyvgl.)

Comment: The same solution will work for 9 boxes.